# How to post array data through serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to post some array data through serializer's create method. How do I get array data in serializer's create method?

this is my result which gives error because of array's data. I have to post belows particular,inch_first...rate arrays data.

```
{
    "order_media": {
        "client_employee": "4",
        "client": "63",
        "narration": "Print ad",
        "vendor": "68",
        "total_amount": "2590.00",
        "discount_rate_client": "10.00",
        "discount_amount_client": "259.00",
        "service_percentage": "10.00",
        "service_amount": "259.00",
        "client_vat": "388.50",
        "total_receivable": "2978.50",
    },
    "pub_date": "2019-04-03",
    "particular": ["Banner", "Poster", "Plastic banner"],
    "inch_first": ["4", "5", "3"],
    "inch_second": ["4", "5", "3"],
    "size": ["16.00", "25.00", "9.00"],
    "quantity": ["5", "5", "6"],
    "rate": ["10", "10", "10"],
}
```

This is my model

```
class RequestPrintProduction(models.Model):
    particular = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    inch_first = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True,blank=True)
    inch_second = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True,blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=45,blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True, blank=True)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00), null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Party, blank=True, null=True)
    request_id = models.ForeignKey(Request, blank=True, null=True, related_name='requestprint')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.particular
```

this is my api views:

```
class PrintRequestAPIView(ListBulkCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RequestPrintSerializer
```

this is my serializer:

```
class RequestPrintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_media = OrderMediaSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RequestPrintProduction
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        service_request = Request()
        service_request.save()

        validated_data['request_id'] = service_request
        order_media = validated_data.pop('order_media')
        print(order_media)

        online_service_request = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**data)

        order_media['request_id'] = service_request
        order_media = OrderMedia.objects.create(**order_media)

        return online_service_request
```

I expect to post array's data successfully.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of troubles are you facing? What do you mean by "posting an array"? Most of your model's fields are of Char type, `rate` is `decimal` - how are arrays supposed to be treated in this case? Please format your sample json - it is hard to read it. And update your question with expected result for this input.

Comment: Are you POSTing that as JSON or a regular form data? Form data can't contain arrays.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I have to post like first index of all arrays into one row and so on.
I expect to handle those particular,inch_first,inch_second,size,quantity,rate array in create method. As I mentioned that I want to enter first index as a first row and so on.

Comment: @AKX before post I convert data into Json and pass it through ajax.

Comment: Please show desired result for this sample data.

Comment: @IvanStarostin desired result for this sample data , data will be stored into models table and page will be reload. I cannot post it because ajax return an error.

Comment: Add demonstration of the result you're expecting - the rows with field-value - how this sample data is supposed to be transformed into given model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to arrange the post data like below. And then whenever you are initializing `RequestPrintSerializer` for this request initialize  the serializer with many=True. Hope it helps. Good lucks.

```
{
  "order_media": {
    "client_employee": "4",
    "client": "63",
    "narration": "Print ad",
    "vendor": "68",
    "total_amount": "2590.00",
    "discount_rate_client": "10.00",
    "discount_amount_client": "259.00",
    "service_percentage": "10.00",
    "service_amount": "259.00",
    "client_vat": "388.50",
    "total_receivable": "2978.50"
  },
  "request_print_production": [
    {
      "pub_date" : "2019-04-03",
      "particular": "Banner",
      "inch_first": "4",
      "inch_second": "4",
      "size": "16.00",
      "quantity": "5",
      "rate": "10"
    },
    {
      "pub_date" : "2019-04-03",
      "particular": "Poster",
      "inch_first": "5",
      "inch_second": "5",
      "size": "25.00",
      "quantity": "5",
      "rate": "10"
    },
    {
      "pub_date" : "2019-04-03",
      "particular": "Plastic Banner",
      "inch_first": "3",
      "inch_second": "3",
      "size": "9.00",
      "quantity": "6",
      "rate": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a char field in your database, but want to post an array to DRF.  In fact, as the comments mentioned, this is an issue with nearly all your fields.  You seem to get around this by just passing strings in everywhere.

Without database support this won't work directly.  However, if you *do* really want to do this then you are going to have to do some of the work in your own code.  There *are* custom fields for this out there somewhere, probably, but I've never seen 'em.

#### JSON Post Only

Here's an easy way to go about doing that:

1. Declare the field on your serializer directly as a [ListField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield)
2. In the 'validate' function, convert to a string (csv, json.dumps, etc)
3. Note that I'm not checking for empty values, settings defaults, etc.  Please read the documentation (and source) for ListField on your own.

```
class Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    particular = ListField(child=CharField(max_length=10))

    def validate_particular(self, value):
        """Convert the list to a json string, and do extra validation if needed"""
        return json.dumps(value)
```

#### Input & Output (Post & Get)

If you are using this both for input and output, and want to return a list from your model, you are going to need to make a custom field:

```
class ListAsJsonField(fields.ListField):
    """
    Converts an incoming list of string values to json.
    This field is _very_ primitive, lots of edge cases may break it.
    """
    child = fields.CharField(min_length=1) # always use a char field

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, data):
        """Convert to our output representation.  Assumes input is always valid json now"""
        return json.loads(data)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """Convert to the internal value -> database (and validated_data)"""
        return json.dumps(data)

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    particular = ListAsJsonField(required=True, min_length=1)
    ...
```

#### Notes:

Some databases like postgres have a custom JSON field & Array field.  Django ships with fields for those in `django.contrib.postgres`. Using these would imply you also want to fix your other model issues.

What the heck is `ListBulkCreateAPIView`?

Comment: ListBulkCreateAPIView used for request/order post data into database through api
"Concrete view for listing a queryset or creating a model instance."

Comment: Any comments on the actual code though?  Or clarifications on whats actually happening, or on your output when you encounter the error.  You've gotta meet us half way.